# How can I make a loading message visible after a user clicks submit on a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML login form in my ASP.NET MVC application that looks like this:

```
<form action="/Account/Login" class="form" method="post">
   <input name="UserName" size="25" type="text" value="">
   <input name="Password" size="25" type="password">
   <button type="submit" class="glossy">Login</button>
</form>

<div class="loading-mask" id="authenticating">
   <span>Authenticating ...</span>
</div>
```

When the user clicks submit there is a delay before the /Account/Login action is processed and before it returns either with a partial form showing errors or before it takes the user to a new page.

Is there a way that I can make the loading div invisible when the form first appears and then have it become visible after the submit button is clicked. Note that I won't need it to be hidden again as any action after the submit will result in a fresh load of the page.

Note I am looking for some way that does not use jQuery.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just plain javascript?

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply. No my page does not use jQuery? I will update the question to mention that.

Comment: Have you made an attempt ? Have you learnt javascript? We won't just write it for you ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `display` property the to `none` at first.

```
#authenticating {
    display:none;
}
```

And then in the form's code

```
onsubmit="document.getElementById('authenticating').style.display = 'block'"
```

**EDIT**
As [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076743/dave) suggested, it is better to use event listeners.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('form').addEventListener("submit", function(){
    document.getElementById("authenticating").style.display = "block";
}), false);
```

Comment: Ideally however, use event listeners over inline.